# when downloading the zip file from the url it showing like "The requested URL /export/name.zip was not found on this server." using php

Tags: php, mysql, zip, php-ziparchive

Some of the zip files is download but some files showing like "The requested URL /export/1286.zip was not found on this server."

But i am using the same code for both.

```
final_zip($certificate_id);
function final_zip($certificate_id){

$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip_file=$certificate_name.'-licence-documents-'.date("d-m-Y h:i:s").'.zip';

if ($zip->open("$zip_file",ZipArchive::CREATE) === TRUE){

$q_pack="(select * from filename where cerid=$id)";
$res_pack = db_query($q_pack);
if ($res_pack){

$fp = fopen('Package_list.csv', 'w');
while ($pack_row = db_fetch_object($res_pack))
{fwrite($fp, "\n");
foreach ($pack_row as $line) {
$val = '"'.$line.'"'.',';
fwrite($fp, $val);}}

fclose($fp);

$zip->addFile('Package_list.csv', "Package list.csv");

}}$zip->close();
ob_get_clean();

header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$zip_file");
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zip_file));
header("Location: $zip_file");}
```

And also please find the screenshor of the error[image: Error]

Comment: It is already cleared in error that the zip you are trying to download is does not exist on your server.

Comment: @DavinderKumar In server the zip are not creating thats why it showing an error, but some files are creating

Comment: You really need to make an effort to indent this code. This looks like it's been minified, it's really hard to follow.

Comment: Use [`fputcsv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) if you're writing CSV data. Try not to roll your own version of same which is likely heavily flawed.

Comment: I indent the code

Comment: fputcsv the reason, for not download the zip file?

Comment: I tried using fputcsv instead of fwrite, still it showing the same error "404 found"

Comment: It's not clear what this script is named or how it's called.

Answer (score 0):

I saw the your zip file have space, so when create the name please remove all space.

Base on your code you can change as:

```
$zip_file=$certificate_name.'-licence-documents-'.date("d-m-Y h:i:s").'.zip';
```

To

```
$zip_file=$certificate_name.'-licence-documents-'.date("d-m-Yh:i:s").'.zip';
```

or

```
$zip_file=$certificate_name.'-licence-documents-'.date("d-m-Y-h:i:s").'.zip';
```

Comment: while removing also same issue is present

Comment: But in my case some zip files are downloading and some or not downloading